# How to change axis label side

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I need to plot a chart with negative values as follows. As you can see, months are being writen bellow axis, overlaping the value line. In excel 2010, is it possible to put it above?

[image]

Comment: Select the axis labels in the graph.  right click and select something along the lines of format element.  Look for a window to appear on the right,  you should be able to play with the text position there

Comment: @ForwardEd Put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the axis labels in the graph. right click and select something along the lines of format element. Look for a window to appear on the right, you should be able to play with the text position there.

Note you can also select where the X-Axis crosses the axis.  Default is zero, but if you wanted the Axis to appear below you graph you could force it to cross a at say -6%